# Need a hand with grep+regex

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression

I'm trying to find the set of words (if any) that contain two consecutive e’s, and also contains two y’s. But so far I tried following commands ,

```
grep -e '[y&y].*[ee]' -e '[y&y].*[ee]' words2.txt 
grep -e 'y.y' -e 'ee' words2.txt
grep -X '.*[y.y].*&.*[ee].*' words2.txt 
grep -X '.[*y.y].*&.[*ee].*' words2.txt
```

some of these commands gives either two y's or two consecutive e's, but don't give a word that contains both of these conditions. What should I do now?

Comment: Does your `grep` support PCRE?

Comment: what is `-X` option? or is it type for `-x`? also, you need to add some sample input and output, it will show whether there are only single words in a line or multiple among other uses...

Comment: @Sundeep, ast-open's `grep` has a `-X` option for _augmented regexps_ that does support a `&` conjunction operator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the info... haven't come across `augmented regexps` before... will look it up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your file looks something like this:

```
beeyy yeey open iee eey yeefy
funny reenydy jyyee
```

and is called `words2.txt`.  Yes, the contents are kind of random.  This will display the set of words containing consecutive `ee` and two `y` characters:

```
< words2.txt tr ' ' '\n' | grep 'ee' | grep 'y.*y'
```

This first ensures that each word is on its own line with `tr`, then `grep`s for two consecutive `e`, then `grep`s again for two (possibly non-consecutive) `y`.  Since each `grep` is a filter, the end result is the set of words containing both consecutive `ee` and two `y`.

On my input, the result is:

```
beeyy
yeey
yeefy
reenydy
jyyee
```

Comment: thanks so much, I tried so hard yesterday :) It worked at last

Comment: Note that it also find `ybeeyey` (3 `y`s).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Indeed. I interpreted the question to allow for that. It will also catch words with three consecutive `e`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want **exactly two** `y`s and not *at least two `y`s*, with GNU `grep` if built with PCRE support:

```
grep -Pow '(?=\w*y\w*y)(?!\w*y\w*y\w*y)\w*ee\w*'
```

Or with [ast-open `grep`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/att/ast/beta/src/lib/libcmd/grep.c) (2014-01-26 or newer):

```
grep -Xow '\w*ee*\w*&\w*y\w*y\w*&(\w*y\w*y\w*y\w*)!'
```

If you also want at least one sequence of **exactly two** `e`s (and not 3 or more), that is for instance match on `eeyy` or `eeyyeee` but not `eeeyy`), with GNU `grep -P`:

```
grep -Pow '(?=\w*y\w*y)(?!\w*y\w*y\w*y)\w*(?<!e)ee(?!e)\w*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a variant of Fox's answer:

```
grep -Po '\w*ee\w*'  words.txt | grep 'y.*y'
```

if you want exactly 2 `y`s:

```
... | grep -v 'y.*y.*y'
```